# Good way to manage CakePHP, MAMP, and git?

Tags: git, cakephp, mamp

I'd like to get started with using git using the free bitbucket account.

Right now, I'm using Mac along with MAMP.  I have MAMP set my Document Root into my Sites folder, as /Users/kurisukun/Sites.  Then for my cakephp, I just plopped the entire cakephp folder into the sites.  So my folder structure looks like this:

```
/Users/kurisukun/Sites
   app
   cake
   etc..
```

However, when I began trying out the git installation, I noticed that after creating a repository on bitbucket and cloning it into my Sites folder, it creates a sub-folder, such as:

```
/Users/kurisukun/Sites
   myproject1/
      app
      cake
      etc..
```

The problem with this is that it breaks my cake.  I believe it would work if I keep changing my MAMP Document Root to the appropriate webroot folder.  As in the above case, I'd go into MAMP and change the Document Root to /Users/kurisukun/Sites/myproject1/app/webroot.  But when I want to change to another project to run, then I'd have to change the Document Root to say, /Users/kurisukun/Sites/myproject2/app/webroot.

In the end, I would like to be able to use a subfolder structure like this as a way to have multiple cake projects.  Each project will be a cloned git repository.  But, is there a way to not have to change MAMP's Document Root each time I want to run another cake project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a very similar setup to yours, and your folder structure should work nicely, with each of your projects inside of your /Sites directory. You'll just need the appropriate Apache configuration to set up each one of your projects on their own domain. I use `http://{project}.localhost` as the URL for each of my projects. In your httpd.conf (mine is located in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`) you'll want to add a directive for your new project, for example, place this at the bottom of your httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName myproject1.localhost:80
DocumentRoot "/Users/kurisukun/Sites/myproject1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I'm using port 80 for my MAMP, so substitute that number for 8888 or whichever port you're using if necessary. And then you'll just need to set your /etc/hosts file to recognize your new domain. You'll need to edit the file as root, so:

```
$ sudo emacs /etc/hosts/
```

(you can substitute vim/nano/text editor of your choice), and inside the file you'll want to add the line:

```
127.0.0.1       myproject1.localhost
```

And then try hitting http://myproject.localhost in your browser -- or http://myproject.localhost:[port] if it's not 80 -- and you should be all set!